# why the measure Amount doesn't change within Request No and order no?

Tags: ssas

I have the following design

[image]

[image]

why the measure Amount doesn't change within Request No and order no?[image]

Comment: Is the measure group related to those dimensions?   What columns are the relationships on?

Comment: based on the information provided I think you have proceed only Dimension, You need to Process Full cube.